# How do you handle a template ng-click in both a directive and controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have a directive with a template (basically two buttons with ng-click on them).

```
app.directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            onNext: "=",
            onPreviousClick: "="
        },
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button ng-click='onPreviousClick($event)'>Prev</button> <button ng-click='onNextClick($event)'>Next</button>",
        link: function($scope){

            $scope.onPreviousClick = function(){
               console.log("Prev click event from directive");
            }
            $scope.onNextClick = function(){
               console.log("Next click event from directive");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now when I use the directive, I want to set the click handler to do work in the controller.

```
<foo on-previous-click="ctrl.onPreviousClick($event)"></foo>

app.controller("myController", function($scope){

    this.onPreviousClick = function(){
       console.log("Prev click from the controller.");
    }

});
```

Basically I want the click event to "pass-through" both the directive and controller. I want both event handlers to fire for the previous button click.

But I can only get one or the other click handler to work. If I comment out my directive handler, the controller works, and vis versa.

Comment: Whats the problem calling the controller method in $scope.onPrevClick?

Comment: @Karthik - Thought about doing this, but I wanted to know if there was a more "preferred" method of doing this.

Comment: what about encapsulating in a function your directive method and the controller method ?

Comment: I would go with the answer PSL has just posted. That would be the right way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally to use the function binding `&` not two way binding, and just make the call from the directive handler as well.

```
return {
    scope: {
        onNext: "&",
        onPreviousClick: "&"
    },
```

and pass the event through to the bound handler via key value pair, i.e

```
    $scope.onPrev({$event: $event });
```

So you could either do it in the link function:

```
 $scope.onPrevClick = function($event) {
    console.log("Prev click event from directive");
    $scope.onPrev({
      $event: $event
    });
  }
```

Or on the template itself.

```
 <button ng-click='onPrevClick($event);onPrev({$event:$event})'>Prev</button>
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrrl', function($scope) {
  this.onPreviousClick = function() {
    console.log("Prev click from the controller.");
  }
  this.onNextClick = function() {
    console.log("Next click from the controller.");
  }
}).directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onNext: "&",
      onPrev: "&"
    },
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<button ng-click='onPrevClick($event)'>Prev</button> <button ng-click='onNextClick($event); onNext({$event:event})'>Next</button>",
    link: function($scope) {

      $scope.onPrevClick = function($event) {
        console.log("Prev click event from directive");
        $scope.onPrev({
          $event: $event
        });
      }
      $scope.onNextClick = function() {
        console.log("Next click event from directive");
      }
    }
  }
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrrl as ctrl">
  <foo on-prev="ctrl.onPreviousClick($event)" on-next="ctrl.onNextClick($event)"></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess there's no way to name the two event handlers the exact same is there? Would that be the only caveat?

Comment: @Matt You should not, since the directive defines the contract you can easily control that. And name of the handler in the controller does not matter. All it matters is that  function binding name on the scope and the handler you define in the directive cannot have the same name since one will overwrite another.